# want to test assertion of integer value should be >3 in Karate API

Tags: api, cucumber, bdd, karate

json response is "Value": 0.23

i want to put assertion here  value should be less than 3 so how to do this ?
tried some examples in documentation but they are for array format of jsonenter code here

Scenario: Shows the minimum time any DB request to CS will take This value is an important indicator for the performance of the database access.

```
Given path 'admin/rest/status/db/'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response contains { Value: ">3"}
 * match Value == { '#? _ > 3' }
* match $.Value == '##[_ > 3]'
* def H = response
* print H
```

tried with above assertion not found any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct it as below:

```
* def resp = { "Value": 0.23 }
* match resp == { "Value": '#? _ < 3' }
* match resp.Value == '#? _ < 3'
```

Comment: there is also a simpler: `* assert resp.value < 3`

Comment: i tried with above examples but giving error ,  

response of API is {"Value":0.21,"Unit":"ms","Description":"Minimum Request Time: 0.21 ms","ValueWarning":1,"ValueCritical":2,"Details":[],"Status":0,"StatusDescription":"OK"}   



$.value will fluctuate after every execution

so what to store in def resp?

and how to assert ?

Comment: Sharing the error message would have helped. The example shared above is self contained that you can run independently in a feature file and check. To incorporate it in your code, you have to code it as: * match $.Value == '#? _ < 3'

Comment: Thanks .. its working accurate with  *match $.Value == '#? _ < 3'