# How to put "OR" operator in Karate API assertion statement

Tags: karate

I would like to use "OR" operator for assertion statement in Karate API.

This is the first time I am trying to OR operator in Karate API:

```
 match response.items[0].type == 'Purchase'
```

I would like to use an OR operator like:

```
 match response.items[0].type == 'Purchase' or 'Freeplay'
```

I have not been able to successfully execute with or statement

Comment: please see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes [`assert`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#assert) is the simplest option:

```
* def itemType = response.items[0].type
* assert (itemType == 'Purchase') || (itemType == 'Freeplay')
```

There are other ways, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377284/143475